# Php and Xpath getting the element with specific index

Tags: php, xpath

```
$td = $xpath->query("//table/tr[2]/td[count(//table/tr[1]/td[.=CCCCC]/preceding-sibling::td)+1]");
echo $td->nodeValue;
```

This is my xpath code and this is my html code:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>AAAA</td>
        <td>BBBB</td>
        <td>CCCCC</td>
        <td>DDDDD</td>
        <td>FFFFF</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1111</td>
        <td>2222</td>
        <td>3333</td>
        <td>4444</td>
        <td>5555</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

For example, I want to get CCCCC's index and in the second row I want to get 3333 by using that index. The code above doesn't work actually it gives empty result.

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DOMXPath::query` returns a `DOMNodeList` object, not a single matching element.

Instead of

```
$td->nodeValue
```

you need to use

```
$td[0]->nodeValue
```

The answer from **gtosto** also applies - your original xpath query will return the wrong element.

See: https://eval.in/909445

Comment: object(DOMNodeList)#3 (1) { ["length"]=> int(0) } 

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

I still got this error.

Comment: Not sure what more I can add on top of the working example - can you edit the question with your full code please?

Answer (score 1):

I think you only forgot the apos around CCCC try

```
//table/tr[2]/td[count(//table/tr[1]/td[.='CCCCC']/preceding-sibling::td)+1]
```

Comment: it works for me, check it [here](https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html)